# Missing views in android?

Tags: android

So Im working in android and I'm using the xml graphical layout editor to edit my xml layout. I'm looking through the possible "views" I can use but in the [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) it lists many more views than are shown in the graphical layout editor.

At the moment I'm looking for the calendar view but I would eventually like to find them all for the future. Am I missing these views or are they somewhere i can't find?

If it helps I'm running the dev kit inside eclipse and I have updated everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no Calendar view.

You can use a [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) or get some ideas from the [Android's Calendar app's src code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git;a=summary).

Comment: I'm probably confused but what is this then? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html

Comment: @Peter: In the api documentation, look at upper right part. Under the search box, there is an option `Filter by API level`, check that and set the API level you are using. :) This will hide the things that are not in the SDK you are using and help keeping the confusions away.